# How to show numbers in native language format

Tags: c#, gdi+, tostring

I am trying to show a column of numbers in the language for which the computer has been set.

Take some sample code...

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Paint += Form1_Paint;
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Font font = new Font("Calibri", 12.0f);
        decimal amount = 12345.67m;

        e.Graphics.DrawString(amount.ToString("N", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture), font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 10.0f, 10.0f);
    }
```

I run it, and as to be expected, I see "12,345.67"

[image]

If I set the computer to a non Latin language (such as Bengali) I get the exact same output whereas I would expect to see it converted to the digits of that language.

Pushing numbers into tooltips, edit boxes etc, the numbers show as expected for the language Windows has been set to so I suspect it is something to do with the Graphics object.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for what I am doing wrong?

EDIT:

I expect to see something like the following mock-up...

[image]

EDIT 2

With computer set to Bengali and modifying the code (the number just put in as a string)...

[image]

I still get the original output (English numbers only) when I run the program.

Comment: It can't be anything to do with `Graphics` it *must* be to do with `decimal.ToString`, because once you call it, all you have is a `string`, as evidenced https://dotnetfiddle.net/WEwjz2

Comment: @Charlieface But if you run it in a non-English languages, surely the string would then be non-English also?

Comment: You do not need a new font object every single time the form paints - it is causing your app to leak badly.  Make one and reuse it

Comment: Not sure what you mean: please show me what `numbers show as expected for the language` is supposed to look like. Bear in mind most here do not speak or read Bengali

Comment: @Ňɏssa Pøngjǣrdenlarp This was just a quick mock up for an example. My real code is better written.

Comment: @Charlieface I don't read Bengali either, that was just a random language I picked for the example. What I expect to see is the digits of the computer systems currently set language, be it Greek, Arabic, Bengali or any other language of choice.

Comment: Please read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#numeric-format-specifier-n to see what the different format specifiers do, note the lack of any specification of the actual standard 0-9 Arabic numerals, because they don't change. If you can show what you *expect* to see, and what other method will produce that result, perhaps there is something to discuss

Comment: @Charlieface I have edited the initial question to show what I expect to see. I have already tried everything on the link you mentioned. Like I said in the question, I can push the same string into a tooltip text hint and get the results I am after, so I still think this is a GDI/Graphics object issue. I figure it has to be something simple I am missing, but cannot work out what.

Comment: I think you want to look into [globalization-localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/globalization-localization/?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: @damichab - When I call `12345.67m.ToString("n", new CultureInfo("bn-BD"))` I get `12,345.67`. It seems that is the Benglai format for `12345.67m`.

Comment: @Enigmativity If you open notepad, type 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 and save, install another language and set windows to use that language (eg Bengali), open up the file  just created, you will see the numbers are in non-english characters. Ditto for using a tooltip text within the program.

Comment: Please paste that code *as text* in order for us to have a [mre]. It looks like it's just a font issue (you wouldn't use Calibri, rather another font which shows `0123456789` in that way), as there is no way you can use other characters in numeric literals in code.

Comment: @Charlieface OP is looking for something that uses NativeDigits from NumberFormattingInfo… which is unfortunately not used by any of .Net formatting code.

Comment: I put a screen shot in so you could see what it looks like on my machine. Cutting and pasting the code, it all reverts back to English characters, which defeats the purpose of the example. The original example therefore still stands.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Are tooltips not part of  .Net formatting code? More than anything, I would expect to see the same results in both places? Not english characters for one, and non-english for the other.

Comment: It's the font, just the font. When you change the language, it also changes the standard font in tooltips. The characters are the same, as you have realized by copying them into [so]. Try `SystemFonts.DefaultFont`

Comment: @Charlieface I have tried other fonts,  "Arial Unicode MS", "Microsoft Sans Serif", "Arial". What standard font should I be using? It would be nice if it was just that simple!!

Comment: @Charlieface Just tried SystemFonts.DefaultFont, still the same results.

Comment: @damichab - I'm not arguing that Bengali doesn't have different characters than the Arabic numerals. All I'm saying is that the .NET culture code doesn't use them.

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes thanks. I was afraid that was going to be the answer. Bit of an oversite from MS. By the way, it is not just Bengali, but every other language that does not use  Latin numbers as well.

Comment: Yes, definitely an oversight.

Comment: @Enigmativity I'm pretty sure that it is actually explicit decision and not oversight. At very least for web pages using non-Western-Arabic  is problematic as search engines were not really good at understanding those back in the days... may not be the case now but changing behavior after 20 years is kind of hard... (If one needs [NativeDigits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.nativedigits?view=net-5.0) to write replacement themselves - it is there and trivial to do)

Answer (score -1):

I think this will helps you:

```
       private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Font font = new Font("Times New Roman", 12.0f);
            var amount = 12345.67m.ToString();
            e.Graphics.DrawString(amount, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 10.0f, 10.0f);

            e.Graphics.DrawString(ConvertToBengaliNumerals(amount), font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 10.0f, 30.0f);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(ConvertToEasternArabicNumerals(amount), font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 10.0f, 50.0f);

        }
        public static string ConvertToBengaliNumerals(string textAscii)
        {
            return string.Concat(textAscii.ToString().Select(c => (char)('\u09E6' + c - '0')));
        }

        public static string ConvertToEasternArabicNumerals(string input)
        {
            var utf8Encoder = Encoding.UTF8;
            var utf8Decoder = utf8Encoder.GetDecoder();
            var convertedChars = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            char[] convertedChar = new char[1];
            byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 217, 160 };
            char[] inputCharArray = input.ToCharArray();
            foreach (char c in inputCharArray)
            {
                if (char.IsDigit(c))
                {
                    bytes[1] = Convert.ToByte(160 + char.GetNumericValue(c));
                    utf8Decoder.GetChars(bytes, 0, 2, convertedChar, 0);
                    convertedChars.Append(convertedChar[0]);
                }
                else
                {
                    convertedChars.Append(c);
                }
            }
            return convertedChars.ToString();
        }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: That is a very nice answer. Unfortunately I won't be able to use it as I am targeting many languages and this will get somewhat unwieldy if I have to write a method for each one. At the point my code from which the example is taken, is run, I do not know what language the computer is set at - it could be Chinese, French German etc. I have been using Bengali as an example simply because that is what I am currently working on. The problem still remains on each non-English character set I have thus far done.  I just wanted you to know that I appreciated the response.

Comment: You may implement it by using https://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/ Unicode Character Ranges by Country. In ConvertToBengaliNumerals method i showed it how to use

Answer (score -2):

Use **amount.ToString("n", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name)**

```
       private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Font font = new Font("Calibri", 12.0f);
            var amount = 12345.67m;

            //seting culture programmatically:
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US", false);

            e.Graphics.DrawString(amount.ToString("n", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name))+" - "+ CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 10.0f, 10.0f);

            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("ru-RU", false);

            e.Graphics.DrawString(amount.ToString("n", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name)) + " - " + CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 10.0f, 30);

            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("eu-ES", false);

            e.Graphics.DrawString(amount.ToString("n", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name)) + " - " + CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 10.0f, 50);

            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("de-LI", false);

            e.Graphics.DrawString(amount.ToString("n", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name)) + " - " + CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 10.0f, 70);
        }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: None of which answers the question: the numerals `1234567` never change